# Assistance with writing/reading to and from vector in JAVA

Tags: java, vector

I have a project where I am required to read and write a vector of bank account objects and I am struggling with this concept. I was able to figure it out when the accounts were not stored in a vector but now that I am dealing with vectors I am confused. If anyone can look at my code I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance for your time!

This is my best attempt. Even though I know it's wrong, I just wanted to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
  public static void readTrans() 
   {    
        textArea.setText("");
        chooseFile(1);  
    try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
             for (int index=0; index != fileIndex; index++)
             {   

                 account = (CheckingAccount)in.readObject();
                 acctStore.add(index, account);
                 System.out.println("reading account " + acctStore.elementAt(index));
             }
            saveStatus = true;
            in.close();                 
        }   
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
                 { 
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }
        catch (IOException e) 
                 { 
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }
   }


   public static void writeTrans() 
   {  
       textArea.setText(""); 
       chooseFile(2);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            for (int index=0; index != acctStore.size(); index++)
             {                                              
                 out.writeObject(acctStore.elementAt(index));       
                 System.out.println("Writing account for " + acctStore.elementAt(index).getName() +" with initial balance: "  + acctStore.elementAt(index).getBalance()); 
                 fileIndex++;
             }
            saveStatus = true;
            out.close();            
        }   
        catch(IOException e)    
                { 
                     System.out.println(e);
                }    
   }
```

## ***UPDATE:***

Ok I think I figured it out however I am getting a warning since I casted the vector onto the CheckingAccount. Is this practice okay? The program is working as I expected so I am assuming so. Thanks again for your time!

Here's updated code:

```
public static void readTrans() 
   {    
        textArea.setText("");
        chooseFile(1);  
    try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);                   

            acctStore = (Vector<CheckingAccount>)in.readObject();

            saveStatus = true;
            in.close();                 
        }   
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
                 { 
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }
        catch (IOException e) 
                 { 
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }
   }
   public static void writeTrans() 
   {  
       textArea.setText(""); 
       chooseFile(2);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);                                                           

            out.writeObject(acctStore);                         
            saveStatus = true;
            out.close();            
        }   
        catch(IOException e)    
                { 
                     System.out.println(e);
                }    
   }
```

Comment: Why not just serialize the entire vector object to write to file then deserialize to read from file.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not sure how I would do that. Would you mind showing me what you mean?

Comment: Try reading about the [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Comment: I understand Serialization to a certain degree but I still do not know how to apply it here. If anyone has some time to show me an example that I could relate to my code I would greatly appreciate it! :)